# Android toolbar only in MainActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

```xml
styles.xml
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

 192.168Manifest

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".app.App">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
  ....
          <activity android:name=".activity.TransferActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

TransferActivity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transfer);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_base);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Transfer activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/activity_transfer_fragment_container"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example">
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_transfer"
    layout="@layout/app_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    />
```

I tried a lot of combinations, but still cant get it working. Toolbar in Main activity is working without problems. But in other activities, eg. `TransferActivity`, I can see only design of toolbar, but it got no text in it.

Comment: you mean title text is there when TransferActivity is displayed?

Comment: I can't find a question in your post. What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Use that instead of  <include>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

Comment: post your toolbar.xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Screen title");
```